# How to Get a Certain Number of Elements from a Django Database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple class:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I get the last five items from the database?

I tried to do this:

```
posts = BlogPost.objects.<any code>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BlogPost.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the array-slicing syntax to index into your queryset, and you use the `reverse()` function to reverse the queryset before indexing, e.g., `myQuerySet.reverse()[:5]`. See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.reverse) for more details.

Comment: What assumptions are you making that reversing the query set will provide the correct ordering?

Comment: @Joe Holloway He said he wanted the last 5 items. I gave him the general solution for that problem. @awithrow's syntax is obviously more idiomatic for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ordering by id it's faster than sorting by any other field.